# Files containing CRS are shown to miss CRS and BASEGEOCRS in QGIS 3.22 and up

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, layer-resource

I am using QGIS 3.22.11 and/or 3.28.7 and have an issue which I believe is corrupted files in the CRS section.
Also in the project selection, there seem to be issues with the WTK files itself.

I have reinstalled QGIS 3.22.11 completely, to remain with the same issue, also on the latest version. This issue does not exist with other pc's in the company, so something is probably wrong on my end. I have checked region settings and disabled firewalls during the install.

The images below show the issue, which is for all CRS, not just the one in the images.
[image]
Project CRS showing unknown PROJCRS and BASEGEOCRS

[image]
Layer imported from another software package containing correct CRS, which now has unknown CRS
[image]
Exported layer from image above, now showing up as unknown (though it is in the correct position)

**EDIT**:
A temporary solution has been found.
I have copied the correct WTK settings from a different pc which didn't have the issue above.
With these WTK properties, i have made user defined coordinate systems.
Not ideal but it is workable. I tested multiple exports and loaded those in on other ps's and the CRS and positions are true.
[image]

Comment: which files do you try to open?

Comment: Its is the same for all files. It is like it somewhere hidden in the root of QGIS.
Every file has the same, it is all unknown, and also the project specific CRS, almost like some essential stuff from the download is missing (or maybe blocked?)

Comment: Try creating a new profile

Comment: There's no need for a CRS to have a name in WKT, or an ID; as long as the parameters, axes, units etc are correctly specified your data will show in the correct place.

Comment: New profiles resulted in the same, good one!
The data is indeed in the correct place, but when it exported and opened on another device it will show up as "unknown".  We also send this to clients, so I can't use this desktop for that

Comment: @nmtoken Unless you need to transform it to another geodCRS, at which point, none of the geodcrs-based coordinate operations will match, unless they too are corrupted.